# EmbeddedDocument in a Document doesn't initialize

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, restframeworkmongoengine

I'm using drf_mongoengine for the first time and I'm having problems setting up the models. I want the documents to be initialized like this:

```
{
    "name" : "new_name",
    "metadata": {
        "total_efficiency": 0.0,
        "eff_vs_layer_thickness":{
            "x":[],
            "y":[]
        }
    }
}
```

The documents are created without the "metadata" field. What Am I missing?

Models:
    class Detector(Document):
        name = fields.StringField(null=True)
        metadata = fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(Metadata, null=False)

```
class Metadata(EmbeddedDocument):
    eff_vs_layer = fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(Plot)
    total_efficiency = fields.DecimalField(null=True, default=0)

class Plot(EmbeddedDocument):
    x = fields.ListField(fields.FloatField(null=True), default=[])
    y = fields.ListField(fields.FloatField(null=True), default=[])
```

Serializer:

```
class DetectorSerializer(mongoserializers.DocumentSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Detector
        fields = '__all__'

 class MetadataSerializer(mongoserializers.EmbeddedDocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Metadata
        fields = '__all__'
```

View:

```
class DetectorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    '''
    Contains information about inputs/outputs of a single program
    that may be used in Universe workflows.
    '''
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = DetectorSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@alvcarmona, welcome to DRF-ME. You're generally doing everything right.

Just a couple of things: you don't need `MetadataSerializer`, as it will be created automatically inside `DetectorSerializer`.

You also shouldn't mix `mixins.UpdateModelMixin` and `mixins.DestroyModelMixin` into a full viewset (`viewsets.ModelViewSet`), instead, mix them into `rest_framework_mongoengine.generics.GenericApiView` (like here: https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/blob/master/rest_framework_mongoengine/generics.py#L16).

Other than that, I think, you're doing everything right. If you can show me your project on github, I could help more.

UPDATE: to mix mixins into generic view, do it [as we do here](https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/blob/master/rest_framework_mongoengine/viewsets.py#L12) e.g.:

```
class PostPutViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
               mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
               GenericViewSet):
    """ Adaptation of DRF ModelViewSet """
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks @Boris Burkov, I realised I was creating the documents without the embedded Documents. I don't understand how to mix the mixins into a generic api view. My repo is this:https://github.com/alvcarmona/efficiencycalculatorweb

Comment: @alvcarmona See my update to the post for an example of ViewSet with only a custom subset of operations allowed.